# iOS Video Player FFmpeg

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, media-player, xcode4.3

So I want to make an app for the iPhone that will play live mms:// video streams.

I have look around, and everywhere says that I'll need FFmpeg in order to accomplish it. So I successfully compiled the FFmpeg libraries, but now

Do I have to convert the mms:// link to a .m3u8 link? Or I can just use apples AV Foundation Framework ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need libmms as well as the ffmpeg libs ,however as think the latest versions of ffmpeg has the code built in so you may not need libmms mms is just a streaming protocol so the actual format is likely some mpeg variant, mp4, h264.

Once you have that you extract the frames , and use ffmpeg avcodec_decode_video2 to decode to an avFrame. Just like any other video.